# Installing Realsense On Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, raspbian-buster, input-device

Hi I am curious if anyone has seen this issue before? When I try to run realsense-viewer, it outputs "Could not initialize offscreen context!"

PS: Followed this https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/installation_raspbian.md

Does anyone who have this working mind running 
`ldd $(which realsense-viewer)` to compare output?

I am running a 05/27/2020 Image of Raspberry Pi Os

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster

Linux raspberrypi 4.19.118-v7l+ #1311 SMP Mon Apr 27 14:26:42 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ realsense-viewer
Could not initialize offscreen context!


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ldd $(which realsense-viewer)
linux-vdso.so.1 (0xbef2c000)
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so (0xb6fb2000)
libatomic.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1 (0xb6f81000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGL.so.1 (0xb6ef4000)
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLU.so.1 (0xb6e8c000)
librealsense2-gl.so.2.34 => /usr/local/lib/librealsense2-gl.so.2.34 (0xb6c1a000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0xb6c03000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb6bf0000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so.6 (0xb6ace000)
librealsense2.so.2.34 => /usr/local/lib/librealsense2.so.2.34 (0xb5a96000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb594f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb58cd000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb58a0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb5876000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb5728000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0xb56a9000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLX.so.0 (0xb568a000)
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6fc7000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb.so.1 (0xb565b000)
libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0xb5636000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXau.so.6 (0xb5623000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb560e000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libudev.so.1 (0xb55de000)
libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libbsd.so.0 (0xb55b6000)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/4193 not sure f it will help.

Comment: @Andyroo yes, that is actually not very helpful :D Unfortunately.

Comment: Seems to be a few on github - video drivers are often blamed!

Comment: Adding this might help someone later on, but doesn't solve https://github.com/acrobotic/Ai_Demos_RPi/issues/1